# Iframe Dom error :cannot read property "src" of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

I putted my editor.html in a iframe using this code :

```
  <iframe name= "iframeEditor" id="ifrm" src="editor.html" width="1000" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

then, i have to access to an element in a script balise in my "editor.html" :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Diagram</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script> 
    <!-- I use many resources -->
    <script> 
        function generatePNG (oViewer) { 
            var oImageOptions = { 
                includeDecoratorLayers: false, 
                replaceImageURL: true 
            }; 

            var sResult = oViewer.generateImageBlob(function(sBlob) { 
                b = 64; 
                var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
                reader.readAsDataURL(sBlob); 
                reader.onloadend = function() { 
                    base64data = reader.result; 
                    var image = document.createElement('img'); 
                    image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage"); 
                    image.src = base64data; 
                    document.body.appendChild(image); 
                } 
            }, "image/png", oImageOptions); 
            return sResult; 
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body > 
    <div id="diagramContainer"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I should access to **image.src** from the iframe that contain my editor.htm so i try with this code :

```
   <script>
var if1 = document.getElementById("ifrm");
var fc = (if1.contentWindow || if1.contentDocument);
var img1 = fc.document.getElementById("GraphImage");
console.log(img1.src);
</script>
```

but i get an error : **cannot read property "src" of null**

Comment: Are you sure that your script is run after image is loaded? Add some console.log to onloadend callback, and check if it's called before error.

Comment: i added console.log in the onloadend callback, but when i run the script i don't get it i just get the error on the console

Comment: and this means that you are running your script before image is loaded. Run Your script at the end of onloadend callback

Comment: i have updated my code :     <script>
function onMyFrameLoad() {
  alert('myframe is loaded');
 var if1 = document.getElementById("myframe");
 var fc = (if1.contentWindow || if1.contentDocument);
 var img1 = fc.document.getElementById("GraphImage");
 console.log(img1.src);
};
</script>

<iframe id="myframe" src="editor.html" onload="onMyFrameLoad(this)"></iframe>

Comment: and the console.log is displayed now, but before it i have an error :Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: Are you launching html page from file system?

Comment: @RafalLuzynski i solved the security error problem, but i still have the error cannot read src of null

Answer (score 0):

You are running script that looks for image element before image is loaded, so it's not yet added to DOM.

move your script to separate function:

```
function yourScript() { 
    var if1 = document.getElementById("ifrm");
    var fc = (if1.contentWindow || if1.contentDocument);
    var img1 = fc.document.getElementById("GraphImage");
    console.log(img1.src);
}
```

and run it at the end of onloadend callback:

```
function generatePNG (oViewer) { 
        var oImageOptions = { 
            includeDecoratorLayers: false, 
            replaceImageURL: true 
        }; 

        var sResult = oViewer.generateImageBlob(function(sBlob) { 
            b = 64; 
            var reader = new window.FileReader(); 
            reader.readAsDataURL(sBlob); 
            reader.onloadend = function() { 
                base64data = reader.result; 
                var image = document.createElement('img'); 
                image.setAttribute("id", "GraphImage"); 
                image.src = base64data; 
                document.body.appendChild(image);
                yourScript();  // your script is run after appending image to body
            } 
        }, "image/png", oImageOptions); 
        return sResult; 
    }
```

Comment: but my function is in the iframe file : <iframe id="myframe" src="editor1.html" onload="onMyFrameLoad()"></iframe>                                    function onMyFrameLoad() { 
    var if1 = document.getElementById("ifrm");
    var fc = (if1.contentWindow || if1.contentDocument);
    var img1 = fc.document.getElementById("GraphImage");
    console.log(img1.src);
}

Comment: when i add it to my editor.html i'm getting error : cannot read document of null and i need to access to the dom from the iframe